# In the long run, what fraction of time spent in state A?

Tags: stochastic-processes, renewal-processes

Consider three random variables X, Y, Z, each of which is not lattice and has finite expectation. A process starts in state A. After a random time X, it moves to state B. Then after a random time Y, it moves to state C, and after a random time Z it moves back to A.This process repeats, with the random times chosen a new from the distributions of X, Y and Z each time. In the long run, what fraction of time is spent in state A?

In this question, every time distribution is changes. Can anyone explain me the direction of this question.

Comment: The standard ways of solving this are (i) as an alternating renewal process or (ii) a renewal rewards process

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mu_x$, $\mu_y$, and $\mu_z$ be the means of the three time distributions of $X,Y$, and $Z$.

As the "formulas" for 
the proportion of time spent in any of the three states are symmetric, it comes intuitively that the proportion of time spent in state $A$ is $\displaystyle \frac{\mu_x}{\mu_x+\mu_y+\mu_z}$.

Another way to think about this is label the time spent in each state as $X_1+Y_1+Z_1+X_2+Y_2+Z_2$......

The proportion of time spent in state $A$ is the time spent in $A$ divided by the entire time, or $\displaystyle \frac{X_1+X_2...}{X_1+Y_1+Z_1+X_2+Y_2+Z_2...}=\frac{n\mu_x}{n(\mu_x+\mu_y+\mu_z)}$

Comment: Ohh Yeah. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: That last equation is a little hard. LHS is a random variable, and the RHS is a constant. I agree with the intuition, but the argument that $$\mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{\sum_{k=1}^\infty X_k}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty (X_k+Y_k+Z_k)} \right] = \frac{\mu_x}{\mu_x+\mu_y+\mu_z}$$ needs to be a little more precise, since $\mathbb{E}[U/V] \ne \mathbb{E}[U]/\mathbb{E}[V]$...

Comment: of course. the precision lies in specifying that the percent variance of $U_1+U_2....U_n$ is less than that of $U$ itself, but i'm relying on intuition here @gt6989b